# How to know the driver was loaded for my USB device in windows enviorment?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, drivers

I am trying to develop some kind of a program to help me know if a USB device I connect to my Windows 8/7 based machine,is loaded correctly in device manager and it's device drivers been loaded correctly without yellow bands.
I am thinking to do it with c++ and visual studio but I cant find any API's which will help me. 
Does someone have any ideas or examples I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Use EnumDeviceDrivers - there's an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682619%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I used to example and it gave me a list of dll's,which really don't give me much.My purpose is to know that the device in plugged in has been enumerated correctly and recognized by windows??

Comment: check following discussion http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/391079/How-to-find-out-when-something-is-connected-to-my and http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/120363-usb-plugin-detection-c-cplusplus.html